# Hydrostatic force problem with trapezoids?

Tags: calculus, integration, physics, applications

If I have a trapezoid with a $4$m and $8$m base that is partly submerged vertically in water so that the top is $2$m above the surface and the bottom is $2$m below the surface; how do I express the hydrostatic force against one side of the plate as an integral?

Comment: Lateral force equals average pressure, times the projected area if I understood right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to find an area equation for the triangle section of the trapezoid where the width is increasing from 4m to 8m, keeping in mind that we're only interested in the area that is submerged in water (2m).

Set up the equation so that you divide the total height (4m) by the maximum width of this section (2m since (8m - 4m)/2, there's 2m on each side). This is equal to the line from the base to the surface of the water (2 - x) divided by a, which is the width at 2-x.

$$
\frac{2-x}{a} = \frac{4}{2}
$$

Isolate for a:
$$
a = \frac{2-x}{2}
$$

Now we can find the area of the trapezoid, which is the base added to double the width of the triangle (a), since the triangle is on both sides of the trapezoid. To find the area, we will multiply all of that by the change in height, which is Δx.

$$
A = (4 + 2\cdot\frac{2-x}{2})\cdot\Delta x
$$

The force is calculated by taking the definite integral on the interval submerged in water of the pressure multiplied by gravity, the change in depth (2-x) and the area equation.

$$
F = \int_{0}^{2} pg(2-x)\text{d}A
$$

Assuming p = 1000 and g = 9.8, we calculate:

$$
F = 1000\cdot9.8\int_{0}^{2} (2-x)\frac{10-x}{2}
$$
$$
F = 9800 [28/3]
$$
$$
F = 91466.6667 N
$$

Comment: This is incorrect.

Comment: Did you figure out the correct solution?

Comment: No :(.  I didn't.

Comment: Ok I edited the solution, please let me know what the correct solution is!

Comment: nope. Still wrong

Comment: I changed it again. Can you check the solution and see if it makes sense..

Comment: It does. Well done, and thank you for the thorough explanation.